# what does "configsvr" mean in db.isMaster() output

Tags: mongodb

I use mongo shell to connect to a mongo config server and below is the output from the command `db.isMaster()`. I don't know what `"configsvr" : 2` means in this output. I searched the mongodb manual but didn't find any description on this field.

```
config:PRIMARY> db.isMaster()
{
    "hosts" : [
        "xxxxx:57040",
        "xxxxx:57041",
        "xxxxx:57042"
    ],
    "setName" : "config",
    "setVersion" : 2,
    "ismaster" : true,
    "secondary" : false,
    "primary" : "xxxxxx 57040",
    "me" : "xxxxxx:57040",
    "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000019"),
    "lastWrite" : {
        "opTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1486443100, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(25)
        },
        "lastWriteDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T04:51:40Z"),
        "majorityOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1486443100, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(25)
        },
        "majorityWriteDate" : ISODate("2017-02-07T04:51:40Z")
    },
    "configsvr" : 2,
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
    "maxWriteBatchSize" : 1000,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2017-02-07T04:51:41.873Z"),
    "maxWireVersion" : 5,
    "minWireVersion" : 0,
    "readOnly" : false,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `isMaster` command is used by MongoDB drivers and `mongos` to discover deployment topology and relevant protocol version details.

The `configsvr` value indicates which config server protocol is in use so `mongos` processes can confirm compatibility.

As at MongoDB 3.4 you might see `configsvr` values of:

- 0 (or absent): original Sync Cluster Connection Config servers (SCCC); MongoDB 3.2 or earlier.
- 1: Config Server Replica Set (CSRS) with MongoDB 3.2 feature compatibility (either MongoDB 3.2 or a deployment upgraded to 3.4 without setting [`featureCompatibilityVersion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/) to "3.4").
- 2: CSRS with MongoDB 3.4 feature compatibility (either a new 3.4 install or a deployment with `featureCompatibilityVersion` set to "3.4" after upgrade).

This field has been noted in the documentation backlog: see [DOCS-9472](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-9472) in the MongoDB issue tracker.